# Debian ssh issue after Buster upgrade

Tags: debian, ssh, remote, ssh-agent

After I upgrade my laptop to Buster (stable) from Stretch (old Stable) I get the following error while I try to connect to my  remote workstation:

```
ssh workstation
sign_and_send_pubkey: signing failed: agent refused operation
workstation@XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX's password:
```

If I type the password I'm able to remotely login. The remote machine run Debian Stretch.

I'm no longer able to connect remote machine from nautilus getting this error:

```
Oops! Something went wrong. 
Don't have permission to access the requested location
```

Maybe the two problems are related.

Comment: Have you tried launch a new SSH agent? Alternatively, rebooting the computer?

Comment: I have upgraded and rebooted both the laptop and the workstation but the problem persist

Comment: Create a new SSH agent and assoc it by `eval $(ssh-agent)`, then repeat the CLI `ssh`, read the failure, add the key by `ssh-add /PATH/TO/THE/KEY`, try `ssh` again, read the failure again. This might hint you the problem. You might then repeat all of those using increased verbosity.

Comment: I tried to resend the key to the client with no luck. I get the same error

Comment: Is your SSH authentication key very old? Try creating a new key; perhaps the old one is too short to be secure by modern standards, or has some other known flaw.

Comment: Found the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44250002/how-to-solve-sign-and-send-pubkey-signing-failed-agent-refused-operation) The problem is related to the permission of the rsa key. In my laptop it was 755 and I found that is no longer accepted. I changed the permission of the files (`chmod 600 id_rsa` and `chmod 644 id_rsa.pub`) and now all works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44250002/how-to-solve-sign-and-send-pubkey-signing-failed-agent-refused-operation)

In particular, the way to solve it is to make sure that I have the correct permission on the id_rsa and id_rsa.pub.

Check the current chmod number by using `stat --format '%a' <file>`. It should be **600** for `id_rsa` and **644** for `id_rsa.pub`.

To change the permission on the files use

```
chmod 600 id_rsa
chmod 644 id_rsa.pub
```

That solved my issue with the update.